# Google Sheets API v4 - I don't want to make spreadsheet public and need to access from cron job

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to keep my Sheets spreadsheet private with "only share with email addresses" but want to get values from cells via API service account with cron job - is this possible without Cloud Account? The cron job will run from linux server.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by a "Cloud Account". You will need to use the Google Cloud Console to establish access to the API.

Once you have done that, you can create a "[Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)" and download the private credentials for this account. You'll then permit the sheet in question to this Service Account through the email address for the account.

When you make the API calls from the program you're executing via cron, you'll [use the credentials of the Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests).

Comment: I mean I don't have the cloud account that askes for "payment method",  I have used "console.developers.google.com" site to make service acount credentials and make project.  Once I get the token back in OAuth part I still get "Caller Does Not Have Permission" error for the email address API manager gave me.  Thanks for your input!!

Comment: Did you permit the email address for the service account to the sheet?